# Can req.params be used to search a model DB

Tags: javascript, mongoose

I created a model, i want to search the model for particular email using  req.params but i don't know if it works

i tried req.body and it works, but req.params and req.query both gives me bad request responds

My codes

```
Const db    = require('./db.connect')
   mongoose = require("mongoose");
     bcrypt = require('bcryptjs');

// MONGOOSE MODEL CONFIGURATION
const UserSchema = new mongoose.Schema({


        email: {
            type: String,
        },
        password: {
            type: String,
        },
});
//presave hook .........
module.exports=mongoose.model('User', UserSchema)
```

My router

```
const
 User = require("../model/user/user.js");
mongoose = required('mongoose');

app.get('/user/:email', (req,res)=>{
    return User.find({email:req.params.email})
      .then(doc=>{
        return status(200).json({doc:doc})
      }
      .catch(err=>{
      return status(400)
      }
})
```

my model contains

```
 app.post("/register", function (req, res) {

    var form = {
        email: req.body.email,
        password: req.body.password,
        }

    User.create(form, function (err, data) {...//do something
```

i get this responds from postman

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <title>Error</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <pre>Cannot GET /user/:email=swam124@gmail.com</pre>
    </body>
</html>
```

on VScode console i get

```
GET /user/:email=swam124@gmail.com 404 22 142ms - 168
```

please help me out

Comment: can you show more of your code including your model schema? query is different from params. query are keys values in the URL after `?` and params are after `:` as in your `/user/:email` - it may be you need to define `mongoose.Promise`

Comment: What is your url?

Comment: And add console.log(req.params.email)

Comment: @Noface About the mongoose.promise, like i said it works with my Post request, because i tried the post method multiple times while trying to resolve this

Comment: @FischerBaba but your post is not using a promise, it is using a callback. Did you try `mongoose.Promise = Promise;`? and when I said `:` for params, I didn't mean that it is inside the URL. Read the god damn documentation. https://expressjs.com/en/api.html#req

Answer (score 0):

your VScode console 404 has the path `/user/:email=swam124@gmail.com`

use the url `http://localhost:3000/user/swam124@gmail.com`

substituting your own host and port details of course

Answer (score 0):

I eventually found a solution. i added `[]`after the search parameter 
`return User.find({email:req.params.email},[])` and the process worked well

```
app.get('/user/:email', (req, res)=>{
        return User.find({email:req.params.email},[])  // added [] here
            .then(doc =>{
                console.log(doc)
                return status(200).json({doc:doc})
            })

            .catch(err=>{
                return res.status(400).json(err)
            })
    })
```

Thanks for the help guys